# UNIX Script - Moving a character in each line of a file

Tags: file, unix

I have a file with multiple records and each record of lenght 100. In each row there is segment of length 50 characters(25-75) which is reserved for State, Country. However now I need the segment to be State,Country(remove space between , and Country) and at the same time maintain the length of the field as 50.

Using Perl command perl -pi -e 's/, /,/g' *.txt I was able to remove the space, however this is reducing the length of the segment to 49. Is there a way I can remove the space and also maintain the length of the segment and also do this for all the records in the file?

Comment: How can you remove a character and expect to have the resulting string have the same length?

Comment: Well the idea is to get the extra space added at the end of Country.

Answer (score 0):

Why use Perl when you can use sed? Try:

```
sed 's/,\(\s*\)\([^,]*\)/,\2\1/g'
```

That moves any whitespace between a comma and a load of non-commas (text) to instead be after the text.

```
a, b, c
```

becomes

```
a,b ,c
```

(with a space after the c)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like we need to do counting - this is the brute-force way:

```
s/^(.{24})([^,]+)( +)(.{,49})(.{25})$/$1$2$4$3$5/;
```

This matches character positions 1-24 in $1; the State part up to the first comma in $2, a string of one or more blanks as $3, the Country as $4, and character positions 76-100 in $5.

The replacement moves the blanks after the Country, thus preserving the length as requested.

What you get if your records are not 100 characters is ... well, probably not what you intended.  You can tweak things quite a lot, but (even though it is untested code), there's a chance this will be adequate, or give you the idea you need.